# Jquery Mobile header menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using the below code to display menu in a native popup form, when user clicks on menu icon on header part, but it simply the shows a blank page with a loader. Please anyone see what is the wrong in the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>IRetail</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/Toast-Plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/ScanditSDK.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.jsonp-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*function success(result) {
                var barcode = result[0];
                //var symbology = result[1];
                document.getElementById("product_id").value = barcode;
                $('#product_id').keyup();
            }

            function failure(error) {
                alert("Failed: " + error);
            }

            function scanBarcode() {
                cordova.exec(success, failure, "ScanditSDK", "scan",
                        ["y5TRWAxOEeKeEGfJ+mo2k17YexeY5gnQXlsZD8bHHPY", 
                        {"beep": true, 
                         "1DScanning": true,
                         "2DScanning": true,
                         "scanningHotspot": "0.5/0.5",
                         "vibrate": true}]);
            }*/



/*function showHint() {
    //alert("Please meet the cash counter to know about offer");
    Toast.longshow("Please meet the cash counter to know about offer");
}*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Xlogix</h1>
            <a href="#mainMenu" data-rel='popup' data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-inline='true' data-transition='pop' data-iconpos="right">Menu</a>
            <div data-role='popup' id='mainMenu' data-theme='d'>
                    <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' style='min-width:210px;' data-theme='d'>
                        <li data-role='divider' data-theme='a'>Choose an action</li>
                        <li data-icon='false'><a href='#' onclick='addQty()'>Add Quantity</a></li>
                        <li data-icon='false'><a href='#' id="remove_btn">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <article data-role="content" id="product_list">
        </article>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="scan_btn" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="top">Scan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="execute_btn" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="top">Manual</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="submit_btn" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="top">Checkout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="cancel_btn" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="top">Cancel</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The direct parent of a popup should be page div, `<div data-role=page>` not any other div.